# How do you set permissions on a schema that has objects accessing other schemas?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, schema

I have 2 schemas and one of the objects in the first schema needs to access an object in the other schema.  For example:

```
CREATE VIEW I.ITest
AS
    SELECT 1 as TestColumn
GO
CREATE VIEW O.OTest
AS
    SELECT * FROM I.ITest
GO

EXEC ('SELECT * FROM O.OTest') AS USER = 'TestUser'

DROP VIEW O.OTest
DROP VIEW I.ITest
```

In the above example, TestUser only has access to the 'O' Schema.  So the select itself works fine, but because the view is doing a select from another schema 'I' then it fails with the error:

> The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'ITest', database 'MyDB', schema 'I'.

To get around this I can give the 'O' schema permission to access the 'I' schema, but this doesn't sound right and looks to be bypassing the schema permissions.

What can be done? Am I doing this all wrong?  Whats the best practice in this scenario?

Thanks

**UPDATE**: My schemas were owned by different db roles so I got around this problem by simply changing the owner of both to dbo and then giving the db role permission to access the schema.  This meant that the owner dbo could see everything and I could then give specific permission to the db role only and the rest of the db objects were not available unless via this schema.  Thanks for your help

Comment: Can you also provide your create user statement and the default schema that each user belongs to please.

Comment: I created the user in via management studio, i.e. not via a script  does it matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should wrap the selection of data from the view on the "other" Schema, within a stored procedure. Then grant execute rights on the stored procedure. Although the user will not have direct access to the view they are permitted access via the stored procedure.

Here is an example walkthrough for you demonstrating the security principles as work:

```
USE DATABASE SANDBOX;

--Create Logins
CREATE LOGIN UserOne WITH Password='Hello123';
CREATE LOGIN UserTwo WITH Password='Hello123';

--Create Database Users
CREATE USER UserOne;
CREATE USER UserTwo;

--Create the Test Schemas
CREATE SCHEMA SchemaOne AUTHORIZATION UserOne;
CREATE SCHEMA SchemaTwo AUTHORIZATION UserTwo;

--Create a View on SchemaOne
CREATE VIEW SchemaOne.ViewOne
AS SELECT 1 as TestColumn;

--Create a View on SchemaTwo
CREATE VIEW SchemaTwo.ViewTwo
AS SELECT * FROM SchemaOne.ViewOne;

--Test that the SchemaOne
EXEC('select * from SchemaOne.ViewOne') AS USER = 'UserOne'
--1

EXEC('select * from SchemaTwo.ViewTwo') AS USER = 'UserOne'
--The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'ViewTwo', database 'SANDBOX', schema 'SchemaTwo'.

--Create a stored procedure to safely expose the view within SchemaTwo to UserOne who's default Schema is
--SchemaOne.
CREATE PROCEDURE SchemaTwo.proc_SelectViewTwo
AS
    select * from SchemaTwo.ViewTwo;

--Grant execute rights on the procedure
GRANT EXECUTE ON SchemaTwo.proc_SelectViewTwo TO UserOne;

--Test the 
EXECUTE AS LOGIN='UserOne';
    Exec SchemaTwo.proc_SelectViewTwo;
revert;
```

An alternative approach as suggeted in my comments would be to use a Database Role to control access to multiple schemas. Using the principals as defined in the solution above, you could use Database Roles like so:

```
EXEC sp_addrole 'CrossSchemaRole';
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'CrossSchemaRole','UserOne';

GRANT SELECT ON SCHEMA::SchemaOne TO CrossSchemaRole;
GRANT SELECT ON SCHEMA::SchemaTwo TO CrossSchemaRole;

EXECUTE AS LOGIN='UserOne';
    select * from SchemaTwo.ViewTwo;
revert;
```

Some suggested further reading:

- [Securing SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb283235%28SQL.90%29.aspx)
- [SQL Server Permission Hierarchy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191465%28SQL.90%29.aspx)
- White Paper: [Security Overview for
  Administrators](http://www.microsoft.com/Sqlserver/2005/en/us/white-papers.aspx#sec)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however this is basically bypassing the schema permissioning, but a long winded way of doing it.  Plus rather than creating sps as wrappers for views, I could instead give the user direct access to the view in the 'other' schema.  All of this though, is still bypassing the use of schemas, which is what I don't want to do.  Maybe the answer is that "YOU SHOULDN'T BE ACCESSING ONE SCHEMA FROM ANOTHER", but I'm not sure this is correct.

Comment: If you wish to grant a specific Database User access to multiple schemas and or schema objects then you should use Database Roles to manage this.

Comment: Yes this is what I have done now, however it is still bypassing the schema permissions. i.e. I now have a user in a db role that now accesses 3 schemas, just because of this scenario.  This sounds dangerous to me, because now either they have access to everything in the other schemas or I need to manually set object by object permissions on the 'other' schema.  What i really want is, if I give user A access to an Object B, that should be it, regardless of what Object B does (i.e. inserts to another schemas object).

Comment: Good stuff, Database Roles are indeed the way to go, although considering the original question posted it sounds as though you may be confusing the use of Schemas for logical seperation of objects, with using Schemas as a securable

Comment: Yeah I was trying to keep the question simple and to the point, but you're right I am confused!! Even though i'm using db roles, I still can't understand why I have to then give the db role access to the other schemas, cos this gives them access to everything and then I may aswell just have given them access directly to that other schema.  Man I'm screwed.

Comment: To clarify, use Database Roles to manage permissions on seucruables such as tables/views and NOT Schemas. Take the time to read through the suggested reading in my post, certainly the first two references and it will become clearer to you!

Answer (score 1):

Surely you give permissions to users not objects and that's it.  If you or the owner of the other schema wants to allow other users to access objects (whether they are tables, views or whatever) within it then it is up to the owner of the other schema.  Just because you as the developer can write a procedure that accesses objects in other schemas it does not follow that anyone running your procedure should be allowed to do so too.  Roles are the way to go.

Comment: Good point regarding my developer ignorance.  Just so happens I have access to all schemas so lucky me.  So I guess you're basically saying either to give them object by object access to the 'other' schema, or complete access via the db role.  I just can't understnad why access isn't implicitly resolved within the object, considering I've given them access to that object.