# 'The SELECT permission was denied on the object ' when working with views on separate schema

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, nhibernate, schema

**Note: This is a community wiki entry and is mainly to document a problem together with its solution. I was hardly able to find information on the net to solve this. Hope it helps someone!**

---

I have a SQL-Server 2005 DB with the data tables being on the `dbo` schema. 
For a new component on the project, I created a new data access layer (using NHibernate) and to nicely capsule this, I created a new schema.

For all the objects I needed, I created a View:

`myschema.ViewTable1`
`myschema.ViewTable2`
etc.
And granted select permission.

Now, when I tried to access these views by a user that only had select permissions on the views but not the underlying table with NHibernate, I got:

`The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'dbo.Table1', database 'TestDB', schema 'dbo'.`

According all the documentation, this should be possible.
Even more strangely, the SQL did work executed in Management Studio as a plain select.
But if I executed it with `exec sp_executesql` as NHibernate does it, it broke with the same exception.

After a long time searching I finally found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661547/how-do-you-set-permissions-on-a-schema-that-has-objects-accessing-other-schemas) question here on StackOverflow.
The added **Update** gave the clue:

My new schema `myschema` was owned by my windows user and not by the **dbo**!

After changing the schema owner to **dbo** and recreation of all the `myschema` objects (**Yes, this is required!**) things start to work as expected!

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solution:

Make sure your schemas are owned by the same role!